# How to adding a fraction with a whole..?

Tags: c#, fractions

how to adding fraction with whole in C#..:
2 + 1 1/5 = ??

or

3 + 3/4 = ?? -----> it's just for example...:), it can be 3 + 2/3 or 4 + 6/7..

help please.. thank you all.. :)

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, in terms of the context.

Comment: I smell homework. Can you do this in any language?

Comment: C# has no built in fraction type, what datatype do you expect as the result, and what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I presume you're seeing odd results due to 3/4 being an integer division. Try (3.0 + 3.0/4.0) which will evaluate as floating point numbers instead.

Comment: Possible Dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360196/how-can-you-add-two-fractions

Comment: Maybe `2 + 1 + 1m/5` and `3 + 3m/4` would be sufficient?

Comment: it's just for example...:), it can be 3 + 2/3 or 4 + 6/7...

Answer (score 4):

Sure, no problem. Download the **[Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1799)** and use the [Rational](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.rational%28v=VS.93%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22MICROSOFT.SOLVERFOUNDATION.SERVICES.PARAMETER.SETBINDING%60%601%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) type to do arithmetic on fractional numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can change each fraction to its equivalent decimal value.
And then operate them.

Remember whole fractions can be used as:

```
1 1/4         => 1 + 1/4
2 1/5 + 2 2/3 => 2 + 1/5 + 2 + 2/3
```

Now, remember for data-type.

```
int i = 1/4;       // it will give 0 since i is int
decimal i = 1/4m   // ok, it will give  0.25;
```

**Example:**

```
decimal i = 2 + 1/5m + 2 + 2/3m;  //it will ok for  2 1/5 + 2 2/3
```

## UPDATE

**C# Code**

```
decimal Fraction(string f)
    {
        var numbers = f.Split(' ', '+');
        decimal temp, result = 0.0m;
        decimal numerator, denominator;
        foreach (var str in numbers)
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(str, out temp))
            {
                result += temp;
            }
            else if (str.Contains("/"))
            {
                var frac = str.Split('/');
                decimal.TryParse(frac[0], out numerator);
                decimal.TryParse(frac[1], out denominator);

                result += numerator / denominator;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
decimal d = Fraction("2 2/3 + 5/7 + 1 1/4");     //4.630952380952380952380952381

// put a space between whole and fraction value   => 1 1/2
// put a + sign to add numbers between them       => 1 2/3 + 2/3
```

*[NOTE: this program is only for addition not for subtraction]*

Comment: Very true, it's also possible wrapping it in some neat class or struct  to make it more elegant to use. :)

Comment: Converting fractions to decimal is lossy.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be "2 + 6/5" or "16/5"? Correct me if I'm wrong but there is no fractions in c#. There is some open source projects for that though.